# Is there private information contained in the Apple System Profiler?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Is there any private information in the Apple System Profiler that would cause you to not want to send it to a third party to troubleshoot a software issue?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your definition of private. The default profile view is the full profile of your machine, which contains your serial number and hardware UUID. Since you are troubleshooting, I find it best to send a Mini Profile(View > Mini Profile) as it contains all of the basic information.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing private stored in the Hardware section.  The Network section may show your system name and IP address/subnet/etc.  The Logs section may contain private information, but it seems unlikely and is highly dependent on the software that wrote the log.  They will likely be able to get your username from the logs.

Note that you can change what is shown in the report by using the View > Short/Standard/Extended Report options and this may help you from sending private information.